# What does the tactic `Induction` followed by a number do?

Tags: coq

What effect does the following tactic have on the goal and the assumptions? 
I know what induction on variables and named hypothesis do, but am unclear about induction on a number.

`Induction 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Coq Reference Manual: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.induction

> (...) `induction num` behaves as `intros until num` followed by `induction` applied to the last introduced hypothesis.

And for `intros until num`: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.intros

> `intros until num`: This repeats intro until the `num`-th non-dependent product.
>
> #### Example
>
> On the subgoal `forall x y : nat, x = y -> y = x` the tactic `intros until 1` is equivalent to `intros x y H`, as `x = y -> y = x` is the first non-dependent product.
>
> On the subgoal `forall x y z : nat, x = y -> y = x` the tactic `intros until 1` is equivalent to `intros x y z` as the product on `z` can be rewritten as a non-dependent product: `forall x y : nat, nat -> x = y -> y = x`.

For reference, there is an index of standard tactics in the Manual where those can easily be looked up: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/coq-tacindex.html

(There are other indices in there that you may find interesting as well.)

Comment: So in your first example, 
    `forall x y : nat, x = y -> y = x`.   
`Induction 1` , applies induction to `x = y`? 
What does a non-dependent product mean exactly? Form your examples, it seems to refer to a quantifier-free formula...

Comment: Yes, that's induction on `x = y`. "Product" here refers to function types: `forall x, F x` has similarities to `Π x, F x` (product over all `x` of `F x`), and in fact `Π` is used instead of `forall` in some areas in the literature. When `F x` is actually a constant `C`, `forall x : T, C` is called a non-dependent product.